# OpenEntityManagerInView equivalent for Junit and Quartz Jobs

Tags: spring, jpa, quartz-scheduler, junit4

Is there any standard way (or substitute to `Open Session [EntityManager] in View`) for usage of classes that depend on Lazy Initialization `(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` of entities in
following two use-cases:

1. In the JUnit test cases
2. In quartz jobs

For both the above scenarios OSIV pattern will not work as no web request enters the system. How to get Lazy Loading work in such situations?

PS: Spring's `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` and `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` are both web request oriented.

1. I can not prefetch all such relations/entites by doing a dummy `get` just to load it before session is closed in the repository(DAO).
2. I know, for JUnit I can manually open/close EM in `@Before` / `@after`. But am looking for something more elegant and standard.

Rerference :
[LazyInitializationException due to no session defined in "parent" application context in Hibernate 3 in a moduled Spring application using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263825/lazyinitializationexception-due-to-no-session-defined-in-parent-application-con)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are what you need.  Open a transaction, fetch the data, manipulate it, then close the transaction when you're done.  Spring binds the `EntityManager` lifecycle to that of the transaction, and holds it open as long as you need.

Spring Transaction Management is a significant subject in itself, but using it is really quite straightforward.  See the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Comment: Well this is exactly why I posted the question, To avoid manually  open/close something(EM/TX) in every job/testcase (dont want to push it to base class and do `extends` stuff). Just wanted to know if there is some better way.

Comment: @kunal: Spring provides transactional unit test support - see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx

Comment: okay cool, I am trying @Transactional. It worked for me in Job but no luck in JUnit so far. Will try some more and update soon. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it worked for JUnit. Was some issue with transitive dependencies of Spring-JPA -> Spring-Dao. Excluded both and it worked. Ref: https://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/spring-dao-2-x-problems/