# OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter Not Working In Unit Test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, controller

I'm writing a unit test for a controller, but when my test reaches the line where it called  this method

```
private Predicate predicate( final Integer pid )
{
    return
            new Predicate()
            {
                public boolean evaluate( Object o )
                {
                    ProviderAuxiliaryAccount proAux = ( ProviderAuxiliaryAccount) o;
                    return proAux.getProviderAccount().getId() == pid;
                }
            };
}
```

It throws a NullPointerException on this line:

return proAux.getProviderAccount().getId() == pid;

When I checked the ProviderAuxiliaryAccount object, It can not seem to retrieve its ProviderAccount property. Therefore, calling getProviderAccount().getId() will surely fire a null pointer exception. But this only happens during the unit test. I suspect that OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter is not working on the unit test.

Here are some excerpts from my java classes:

1. Controller Test class

   ```
   @Transactional
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration( loader = CustomContextLoader.class, locations = {"/applicationContext-web-test.xml","/applicationContext-web-mail-test.xml"})   
   public class ControllerTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
   ```
2. ProviderAuxiliaryAccount model

   ```
      public class ProviderAuxiliaryAccount
            implements Serializable
         {

             private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

             private Integer id;

             private Integer providerId;

             @XmlTransient
             private ProviderAccount providerAccount;
   ```

   3.Here's the part in my actual controller which called the method 'predicate'.

   ```
               List<AuxiliaryAccount> accounts = auxiliaryService.getAuxiliaryAccounts( account.getPerson() );

               ProviderAccount provider = auxiliaryService.getProviderAccount( UserAccountUtil.getUserName() );

               AuxiliaryAccount aux =
                       ( AuxiliaryAccount ) CollectionUtils.find( accounts, PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate() );

               Integer pid = provider.getId();

               if ( CollectionUtils.find( aux.getProviderAuxiliaryAccounts(), predicate( pid ) ) != null )
   ```

Notice that the ProviderAuxiliaryAccount has a transient ProviderAccount property. Also,
I added a @Transactional anotation on my controller test class as stated here. 
[OpenEntityManagerInView equivalent for Junit and Quartz Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017374/openentitymanagerinview-equivalent-for-junit-and-quartz-jobs) .
But this doesn't seem to work for me.

Does anyone know how to fix this?